# Square of an element in an algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime $\neq 2$. Let $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ be the algebraic closure of the finite field with $p$ elements. Let $a\in\overline{\mathbb F_p}$, where $a^2\in\mathbb F_p$ and $a^{p-1}=1$.

> Is it true that, in this situation, $a\in\mathbb F_p$?

The condition $a^{p-1}=1$ gives us that $a$ is a root of unity, and the condition $a\in\mathbb F_p$ probably somehow restricts this to an element in $\mathbb F_p$.
This is probably very trivial, but I can't come up with an easy proof for this.

Comment: If $p=3$ and $a\in\Bbb F_9$ with $a^2=-1$...

Comment: But the field $\mathbb F_9$ does not have prime order

Comment: ... but its order is a power of a prime, all finite field extensions of $\Bbb F_3$ have cardinality a power of $3$, and the fields are building a graph, orders $3^r$ and $3^s$ are related by inclusion (of fields) iff $r$ divides $s$... They are all (isomorphic to) subfields of the algebraic closure, and their union... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness

Comment: But this would contradict the assumption $a^{p-1}=1$.

Comment: So we are looking for an element (which you call $a^2$) in $\Bbb F_p$ which is a $\frac{p-1}2$th root of unity, but doesn't have square roots in $\Bbb F_p$. For instance, $2\in \Bbb F_7$ is a cube root of unity, but fails because it is a square root ($3^2 = 2$). Does this sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must have $a\in \Bbb F_p$. The polynomial $x^{p-1} - 1$ over the field $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ is of degree $p-1$, and thus has (at most) $p-1$ roots. However, every non-zero element in $\Bbb F_p$ is a root of this polynomial, and there are exactly $p-1$ of those. Thus they must be all the roots, and there is no root in $\overline{\Bbb F_p}\setminus \Bbb F_p$